# Jump to SWT Table Cursor's particular cell doesn't work

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have 3 modules in my Eclipse RCP Product in which i have used table cursor :

### Modules :

1. Analytical Part_1 (RCP Editor)
2. Analytical Part_2 (RCP Editor)
3. Errors (RCP View)

### Description:

"Analytical Part_1" & "Analytical Part_2" shall have some records with errors. Errors have been defined in Errors module where clicking on it, my selection & cursor should jump to source of error in first two modules. Error view will be always opened. First two module can be opened from menu.

### Problem :

It jump to source of error when,

1) when product get opened and when there is no module opened and clicking on error it will jump to source.
2) When I have already open the module and clicking on error it will jump to source.

But it won't work when I have error related to first module and when i am in second module and click on error to jump then, module get opened but cursor always jump to first row. Columns are located nicely but row set to first rowIndex.

Situation is below code works for other way around when above two situation happens. I debug the code and i got the exact RowID & ColumnID.

### Code to jump to source of error :

```
if (Module_ID.equalsIgnoreCase("Analytic_PART_1"))
{

    Command command = ((ICommandService) getSite().getService(ICommandService.class)).getCommand(Analytic_PART_1_Handler.ID);

    final Event trigger = new Event();

    ExecutionEvent executionEvent = ((IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class)).createExecutionEvent(command, trigger);

    command.executeWithChecks(executionEvent);

    IEditorPart editorPart = page.getActiveEditor();
    Analytic_PART_1 myEditorPart = (Analytic_PART_1)editorPart;
    Table fit_table = myEditorPart.table;

    TableItem[] tableitemss = fit_table.getItems();
    for(TableItem items : tableitemss)
    {
       if(items.getText(1).equals(rowID))
       {
          int indexcolumn = 0;
          String[] columnName = myEditorPart.colNames;
          for(int i=0;i<columnName.length;i++)
          {
             if(columnName[i].equals(Column_Name))
             {
               indexcolumn = i;
             }
          }

          myEditorPart.tableCursor.setSelection(items, indexcolumn);
          myEditorPart.setFocus();
          break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to change to `myEditorPart.tableCursor.setSelection(rowID, indexcolumn)`

Comment: rowID is actually my value of first column's item. items give me exact row index. It works fine when PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor()==null but when i go to Analytic_PART_2 and then when i click on error then PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor() comes not null at that time it locates to right cell but goes to first row only. I logged and found table's row ID comes exact but doesn't locate.

Comment: same problem SWT Table Cursor's particular cell doesn't work..